# Azure APIM Policy to failover primary backend URL to secondary in case of a time out

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, policies

My requirement is fairly simple. I have an APIM endpoint that calls a backend HTTP service with a predefined timeout. If the request times out or returns an error other than 'Bad Request' (`Status Code > 400)`, the call needs to be retried with a fail-over HTTP service until success or utmost 5 times. I am trying to come with an APIM policy to accomplish this. While the retry and fail-over works if the returned status code is above 400, it doesn't happen if the request simply times out. If the request simply times out, the control doesn't even enter the `<retry>` block. I am fairly certain the retry condition I put in is not being capable to capture the time out condition. Could someone help me figure out the APIM policy to be used to record timeouts?

Below is the APIM policy.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="isFlag" value="true" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("isFlag") == "true")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="<primary url>" />
                <forward-request timeout="5" />
                <retry condition="@(context.Response == null || context.Response.StatusCode > 400)" count="5" interval="1" first-fast-retry="true">
                    <set-backend-service base-url="<secondary url>" />                        
                </retry>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />        
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Below is the excerpt from the APIM trace

```
Inbound
(3.014 ms)
api-inspector (0.403 ms)
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "https://gpcshare-apim-gpc-dev-aes.azure-api.net/statcode/405?sleep=7000",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "value": "a02f7f4e18d54d84ba55d4f122548072"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "103.111.183.78"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Via",
                "value": "ICAP/1.0 bmg70302.ibosscloud.com (IBOSS/0.4.4 iboss ICAP service )"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "gpcshare-apim-gpc-dev-aes.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/apimanagement/Content/1.42.0.1/apimap//apimap-apis/index.html?clientOptimizations=undefined&l=en.en-us&trustedAuthority=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com&shellVersion=undefined"
            }
        ]
    }
}
api-inspector (0.004 ms)
{
    "configuration": {
        "api": {
            "from": "/statcode",
            "to": null,
            "version": null,
            "revision": "1"
        },
        "operation": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uriTemplate": "/{code}"
        },
        "user": "-",
        "product": "-"
    }
}
cors (2.601 ms)
"Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."
cors (0.002 ms)
"Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."
set-variable (0.003 ms)
{
    "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
    "name": "isFlag",
    "value": "true"
}
Backend
(4,991.587 ms)↑ Back to top
choose (0.017 ms)
{
    "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
    "expression": "context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>(\"isFlag\") == \"true\"",
    "value": true
}
set-backend-service (0.007 ms)
{
    "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
    "oldBackendServiceUrl": "",
    "newBackendServiceUrl": "https://httpstat.us/",
    "request": {
        "url": "https://httpstat.us/405?sleep=7000"
    }
}
forward-request (0.151 ms)
{
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 5 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "https://httpstat.us/405?sleep=7000",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "httpstat.us"
            },
            {
                "name": "Request-Id",
                "value": "|f595c50c66d7453c97a7dc14c9c1af9e.2b06f656cb6c4704_b907aebb."
            },
            {
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "value": "a02f7f4e18d54d84ba55d4f122548072"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "103.111.183.78,13.91.254.72"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Via",
                "value": "ICAP/1.0 bmg70302.ibosscloud.com (IBOSS/0.4.4 iboss ICAP service )"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/apimanagement/Content/1.42.0.1/apimap//apimap-apis/index.html?clientOptimizations=undefined&l=en.en-us&trustedAuthority=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.azure.com&shellVersion=undefined"
            }
        ]
    }
}
forward-request (4,991.413 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        "Error occured while calling backend service.",
        "Request to the backend service timed out"
    ]
}
Outbound
(0.183 ms)↑ Back to top
transfer-response (0.067 ms)
{
    "message": "Response headers have been sent to the caller."
}
transfer-response (0.116 ms)
{
    "message": "Response body streaming to the caller is complete."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to have your logic inside the `retry` policy. There is a [policy snippet sample](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Back-end%20API%20redundancy.policy.xml) that you can refer to. Specifically this [line](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Back-end%20API%20redundancy.policy.xml#L37).

Here is the same policy for reference

```xml
<!--
    This policy routes calls to the closest of two backend services, and fails over to the secondary if an HTTP 404 is returned.

    It assumes that the API Manager is deployed in 'East US' and 'West Europe'. Similarly the policy (as is) assumes two backend services, in the same regions, vis:
        https://hello-eus.azurewebsites.net/  (for East US); and
        https://hello-weu.azurewebsites.net/  (for West Europe)

    If a failure (HTTP 404) is returned from the backend service, the policy will re-route the call to the fail-over region.
    The policy uses cached values to track which service has returned an error in the last 10 seconds, to avoid routing new requests to a backend which will likely fail.
-->
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-eus.azurewebsites.net/" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Deployment.Region.Equals("east us", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-eus.azurewebsites.net/" />
                <cache-lookup-value key="@("eus-down")" variable-name="is-eus-down" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("is-eus-down"))">
                        <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-weu.azurewebsites.net/" />
                    </when>
                </choose>
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Deployment.Region.Equals("west europe", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-weu.azurewebsites.net/" />
                <cache-lookup-value key="@("weu-down")" variable-name="is-weu-down" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("is-weu-down"))">
                        <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-eus.azurewebsites.net/" />
                    </when>
                </choose>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)" count="2" interval="1" max-interval="10" delta="1" first-fast-retry="true">
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Response != null && (context.Response.StatusCode == 404))">
                    <choose>
                        <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Host.Contains("hello-eus.azurewebsites.net"))">
                            <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-weu.azurewebsites.net" />
                            <cache-store-value key="@("eus-down")" value="@(true)" duration="10" />
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                            <set-backend-service base-url="https://hello-eus.azurewebsites.net" />
                            <cache-store-value key="@("weu-down")" value="@(true)" duration="10" />
                        </otherwise>
                    </choose>
                </when>
            </choose>
            <forward-request />
        </retry>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```